# Put curly brace on new line after everything except Else in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Simple question: Is it possible, in Visual Studio 2015, to keep curly braces on new lines *except* for those following `else` statements?

This is how VS currently formats it:

```
if(something == true)
{
    //whatever
} else
{
    //whatever else
}
```

But I want it to format like this:

```
if(something == true)
{
    //whatever
} else {
    //whatever else
}
```

Comment: You can probably create a macro to do it. Personally, I'd just do it by hand. I get zero satisfaction out of the IDE formatting code for me. IDE gets it wrong a lot and I have to manually format it then to correct the mistakes.

Comment: @TruthSerum I find it a lot faster to work when the IDE formats braces and stuff for me, but it's annoying if it doesn't quite have enough options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > New Lines > Check the box next to `Place "else" on new line`. You may have to scroll down within the menu to see it.

You may have to mess with some of the other New Lines settings, but there is a lot you can do to make it work how you want it.

Comment: You didn't read my question. I don't want `else` on a new line; that's not the issue. The issue is getting the brace following the `else` onto the same line as the `else`.

I looked in that settings menu quite a lot and I don't know if I'm missing something or if what I want simply can't be done. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted it then. I messed around with the settings some more, and I couldn't get it figured out. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which language you're working with, but for C++, what works for me is to go to the New Lines section of the Tools->Options settings and under "Position of open braces for control blocks" select "Don't automatically reposition".  Then type your curly brace after your else, and it won't be moved.

If it's C# you're working in, go to the same "New Lines" section there, but uncheck "Place open brace on new line for control blocks".  Then just type your curly brace after the else, and it will stay there.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realise language made a difference, but yeah it's C# because I'm working with Unity. Your solution won't work because then the curly braces will go on the same line as `if` and `for`. I want the curly brace on the same line as _only_ `else`.